# UITableview Cell animation

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation

If I am inserting one by one row then this animation is working from bottom to top animation.
and make a condition when you scroll top to bottom at that time not animation, but I want to also stop animation after one time animation from bottom to top.

in `willDisplayCell` of `tableview` method :

```
if (tempIndex == nil)
{
    CGRect myRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //instead of 568, choose the origin of your animation
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x,
                            cell.frame.origin.y + 568,
                            cell.frame.size.width,
                            cell.frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        //instead of -30, choose how much you want the cell to get "under" the cell above
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(myRect.origin.x,
                                myRect.origin.y ,
                                myRect.size.width,
                                myRect.size.height);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            cell.frame = myRect;
        }];

    }];
    tempIndex = indexPath;
}
else if (tempIndex.row < indexPath.row)
{
    CGRect myRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    //instead of 568, choose the origin of your animation
    cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x,
                            cell.frame.origin.y + 568,
                            cell.frame.size.width,
                            cell.frame.size.height);

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        //instead of -30, choose how much you want the cell to get "under" the cell above
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(myRect.origin.x,
                                myRect.origin.y,
                                myRect.size.width,
                                myRect.size.height);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
            cell.frame = myRect;
        }];

    }];
    tempIndex = indexPath;
}
else
{
    tempIndex = indexPath;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can maintain an integer which is an index of the rows up till which the tableview has animated

```
//assuming animatedTill as a property initialized to 0 
    if (indexpath.row > self.animatedTill)
    {
        CGRect myRect = [tableView rectForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

        //instead of 568, choose the origin of your animation
        cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x,
                                cell.frame.origin.y + 568,
                                cell.frame.size.width,
                                cell.frame.size.height);

        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
            //instead of -30, choose how much you want the cell to get "under" the cell above
            cell.frame = CGRectMake(myRect.origin.x,
                                    myRect.origin.y ,
                                    myRect.size.width,
                                    myRect.size.height);

        } completion:^(BOOL finished){
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
                cell.frame = myRect;
                self.animatedTill = indexpath.row
            }];

        }];
    }
```

Comment: thank you...but i have a already solved that issue using  NSMutableArray and comapare that [animatedIndexPathArray containsObject:indexPath]

Comment: In my opinion, using this integer approach versus an array would use much less memory and CPU.